# Can I multiply charAt in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

When I try to multiply charAt I received "big" number:

```
String s = "25999993654";
System.out.println(s.charAt(0)+s.charAt(1));
```

Result : 103

But when I want to receive only one number it's OK .

On the JAVA documentation:

```
the character at the specified index of this string. The first character is at index 0.
```

So I need explanation or solution (I think that I should convert string to int , but it seems to me that is unnesessary work)

Comment: You're not multiplying there, you're adding. Also, the output you say is "100" is actually "103".

Answer (score 12):

`char` is an [integral type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1). The value of `s.charAt(0)` in your example is the `char` version of the number 50 (the character code for `'2'`). `s.charAt(1)` is `(char)53`. When you use `+` on them, they're converted to ints, and you end up with 103 (not 100).

If you're trying to use the *numbers* `2` and `5`, yes, you'll have to parse them. Or if you know they're standard ASCII-style digits (character codes 48 through 57, inclusive), you can just subtract 48 from them (as 48 is the character code for `'0'`). Or better yet, as Peter Lawrey points out elsewhere, use [`Character.getNumericValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29), which handles a broader range of characters.

Comment: +1, I was going to reply with this but you beat me to it (and i was baffled at how he got 100 and wasn't brave enough to say it should be 103).

Comment: @SnowBlind: LOL, took typing in high school. Some of the best advice my mother ever gave me (and she gave me a lot of good advice -- much of which I failed to heed, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you should parse extracted digit or use ASCII chart feature and substract 48:

```
public final class Test {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        String s = "25999993654";
        System.out.println(intAt(s, 0) + intAt(s, 1));
    }

    public static int intAt(String s, int index) {
        return Integer.parseInt(""+s.charAt(index));
        //or
        //return (int) s.charAt(index) - 48;
    }
}
```

Comment: Character.getNumericValue() may be a better choice here.