# Can I product of charAt in Java?

Tags: java, string, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I multiply charAt in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686648/can-i-multiply-charat-in-java)

When I compile this :

```
String s = "25999993654";
System.out.println(s.charAt(0)+s.charAt(1));
```

I received 100

JAVA documenation :

```
the character at the specified index of this string. The first character is at index 0.
```

I think that I must compile string to int , but I think that it is unnesassary job . Any solutions or idea ?

Comment: Do you keep posting the same question every 20 minute?

Comment: Why you ask same question two times.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686648/can-i-multiply-charat-in-java

Comment: You must be revieving 103 and not 100. It confused me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
String s = "25999993654"; 
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(0)) 
         + Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(1)));
```

Comment: Thanks , this was helpful for me . I did what I want. :D

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse it to int

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0))) + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(1)))
```

Comment: Isn't this too heavy for the tast? String -> char -> String -> int

Comment: Because you are not certain that it will contain integer only, proper exception needs to be taken care

Comment: @Michael Borgwadt's solution (correctly) uses the parse-character-to-digit method provided in `Character`.

Answer (score 1):

Its adding the ascii value of the characters.

You can get int equivalent by minusing 48.

```
System.out.println((s.charAt(0)-48)+(s.charAt(1)-48));
```

or make a function to convert ascii to number

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want the result to be 2 + 5 = 7:

```
System.out.println(Character.digit(s.charAt(0), 10) + Character.digit(s.charAt(1), 10));
```

This is necessary because `charAt()` returns a character, which is basically a Unicode ID number.

Answer (score 0):

The value of charAt() is not the integer but the ascii value

[Ascii Table](http://www.google.be/imgres?um=1&hl=fr&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla%3afr%3aofficial&channel=fflb&biw=1280&bih=921&tbm=isch&tbnid=_mIC2A1Zjxd_9M%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/files/ascii.htm&docid=2ZsI_Y12d04qXM&imgurl=http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/Professeurs/Alain/images/ASCII1.GIF&w=560&h=600&ei=kn4SULmABIah0QWi_YDACQ&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=243&sig=101520634645354245171&page=1&tbnh=160&tbnw=149&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:11,s:0,i:172&tx=44&ty=9)